# Delaying Dropbox startup on Windows

Tags: windows-7, dropbox, delay

I am using Startup Delayer from R2 Studios during my Windows 7 startup. However the only app currently which seems that I cannot influence is Dropbox. I had moved the Dropbox from the standard startup to the Startup Delayer controlled database.

Since Dropbox updates pretty frequently it got somehow back to the startup but I cannot find it anywhere. There is nothing in AppData/...../Startup, nor C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Startup, nor Run key in registry under HKCU and HKLM, (now it is getting awkward) nor the Services, nor Tasks (maybe here I overlooked something but I doubt it).

The question is then simple. Does anybody knows specifically where Dropbox stores their autolaunch settings (in the latest releases) or where to look?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check for the Start Menu startup folder or with msconfig ?

Answer (score 1):

I know if you disable Dropbox startup on launch in the registry using an editor - 
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Startup

It just overwrites this change when Dropbox next runs. You have to actually change the setting in Dropbox preferences to stop it overwriting. Maybe this is effecting the Startup Delayer? Maybe if you turn the autostartup off in Dropbox preferences then manually make it a startup item, the delay won't get overwritten? If that's even what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're running into is that Startup Delayer is not capturing Dropbox consistently to have it run when you want. You have to turn Dropbox startup off, then include it manually within Startup Delayer.

In some instances, if the "Start Dropbox on system startup" does not apply, you may need to run Dropbox as Administrator to change the preference permanently.

In Dropbox 3.4.0:

- go to Preferences
- uncheck "Start Dropbox on system startup"
- Add Dropbox to Startup Delayer

Even after these steps you still run into issues, you will need to submit a bug report to Dropbox. My workaround to the issue was to upgrade from a hard disk to solid state.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alcafly. I've never personally experienced this issue (across thousands of computers) with DropBox whenever I've manually disallowed it from running on startup. If your using a 3rd party application to control the startup process then I suggest using [MSCONFIG](http://www.netsquirrel.com/msconfig/) to completely disable (DropBox's) control over automatically starting. This should also prevent it from reverting back after an update.

You didn't mention it in the things you've tried so from there I would think that Startup Delayer would still have control over DropBox processes.